# Invalid block type while using pdfbox 2.0.8

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to use PDFBox to get text from a PDF but I'm running into an exception. Here's the code I'm using to do the text stripping.

```
  try
  {
     PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(decodedPdfDocument.getBytes());
     PDFTextStripper Tstripper = new PDFTextStripper();
     String st = Tstripper.getText(document);
     System.out.println("Text:" + st);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

And here's the exception I'm getting.

```
java.io.IOException: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid block type
    at org.apache.pdfbox.filter.FlateFilter.decode(FlateFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSInputStream.create(COSInputStream.java:69)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.createInputStream(COSStream.java:167)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.getContents(PDPage.java:155)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFStreamParser.<init>(PDFStreamParser.java:91)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:485)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:469)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:150)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.LegacyPDFStreamEngine.processPage(LegacyPDFStreamEngine.java:139)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:391)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPages(PDFTextStripper.java:319)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:266)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.getText(PDFTextStripper.java:227)
    at com.cerner.fsi.testing.xds.provideandregister.ClinicalEventInErrorTest.testProvideAndRegisterCDAWrappedDocument_ClinicalEventInError(ClinicalEventInErrorTest.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at com.cerner.fsi.testing.xds.EnterpriseClientSpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1$1.run(EnterpriseClientSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at com.cerner.fsi.testing.xds.EnterpriseClientSpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1$1.run(EnterpriseClientSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.cerner.fsi.testing.xds.EnterpriseClientSpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(EnterpriseClientSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid block type
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:259)
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:280)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.filter.FlateFilter.decompress(FlateFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.filter.FlateFilter.decode(FlateFilter.java:74)
    ... 49 more
```

I've ran the PDF through validation and it's a valid 1.4 PDF. I'm also able to extract text using both Foxit and Acrobat frontend tools. Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here, this is my first time using this API.

Comment: Might be an encoding error. Have you tried specifying the file's actual encoding to your library?

Comment: I tried using `decodedPdfDocument.getBytes("UTF-8")` instead but I'm getting the same error. The decodedPdfDocument comes from decoding a Base64 string. I'm creating a new string using `new String(Base64.decode(documentString), "UTF-8");`

Comment: Please share the PDF in question (or a similar one unexpectedly producing the same error) for analysis.

Comment: Am I able to attach files in SO or should I link a dropbox/google drive link?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xjeksj0cay4x3vo/NoTemplateInError.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Any luck with the PDF attachment?

Comment: It works fine. Don't store a PDF in a string. `PDDocument.load(Base64.decode(documentString))` should be all you need. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html#decode-java.lang.String-

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue either. If `decodedPdfDocument` indeed is a `String`, then @Tilman most likely has spotted the error. Never ever treat binary contents (like PDFs) as text!

Comment: I'll give that a shot and see what happens.

Comment: That did it! Thank you both for your help, consider this a lesson learned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a comment of the OP

> The `decodedPdfDocument` comes from decoding a Base64 string. I'm creating a new string using `new String(Base64.decode(documentString), "UTF-8");`

This is the error. Never ever treat binary contents (like PDFs) as text! Instead let the decoded PDF document remain a `byte[]`:

```
documentString = [...your base64 encoded PDF ...];
byte[] decodedPdfDocument = Base64.decode(documentString);
...
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(decodedPdfDocument);
PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
String st = textStripper.getText(document);
```

---

As a background: When you do something like

```
String string = new String(bytes, encoding);
```

for a `byte[] bytes`, your `bytes` are decoded assuming they contain text encoded to bytes using `encoding`.

If your `bytes` are not text encoded using `encoding`, this process can be destructive, byte sequences that don't make sense according to the assumed encoding will be converted to a replacement character in the `String`. When you later retrieve bytes from the String using `getBytes()`, you'll retrieve representations of the replacement character instead of the original byte sequences.